# Clean url in php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

**Clean url in php using htaccess** 
Here is an example

http://www.example.com/Mobiles/index.php?idd=4

and i want result like this

http://www.example.com/Mobiles

Please help

Comment: You don't want to pass the `idd=4`  in the new url ?

Comment: yeah..  don't want to pass it and also i don't want to display index.php

Answer (score 1):

This is called `URL Rewrite`. If your page links are dynamic, like extracting data from database which is mostly the case in e-commerce sites, then the best approach is to append the `id` at the end of URL. This way you can fetch the data from database. Like in your case, your new URL might look like:

```
http://www.example.com/Mobiles/4
```

When user will visit this link `.htaccess` file will internally rewrite this URL to:

```
http://www.example.com/Mobiles/index.php?id=4
```

In this way you can then retrieve `id` from your PHP like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

or:

```
extract($_GET);
```

This `extract` function will create the variables automatically from the parameters name and you can access it directly with `$id` variable.

Here is the `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Mobiles/(\d+)$ http://www.example.com/Mobiles/index.php?id=$1
```

In case if you don't need URL like `http://www.example.com/Mobiles/4`, then use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Mobiles$ http://www.example.com/Mobiles/index.php?id=4
```

Comment: thnks for rply.. let me try it.. and can u please tell me if i have multiple links like this then i have to write the above code for multiple times ?

Comment: @RajeshKumar No, only one entry in `.htaccess` is all you need, if your URL is in this format `http://www.example.com/Mobiles/index.php?id=4`. If your `id` is different, then use the first example of .htaccess I posted that will accept any `id`.

Comment: thnks.. bt i mean to say if i have many categories like mobile , TV etc etc .. in that case what to do ? can u please tell me..

Comment: This is a different thing now. Your actually question is completely different from what you are asking now. In this case mostly the categories id's are added in parameters like `cat-id` and then it needs slight modification in .htaccess.

Comment: thnks for reply.. Actually i got ur answer that u have told me above to rewrite url.. bt i was asking if there are many categories .. so in that case can i generate url like this  http://www.example.com/Mobiles/4     http://www.example.com/TV/2     http://www.example.com/AC/1

Comment: Yes, but with slight modification in .htaccess. Replace the Mobiles with `(Mobiles|TV|AC)` in first `.htaccess` example.

Comment: thnku  its working.. bt how to give the link mobile to open mobiles..   e.g. <a href="Mobiles/index.php?idd=<?php echo $idd;?>">Mobiles</a>..  it was like this..now if i write only Mobiles in href tag its show no recordsin database.. and if i write whole line then htacces is not working..please help

Comment: hello sir.. i follow your answers but it doesn't hiding url.  its giving output like this  http://www.example.com/Mobiles/index?idd=1                             .. but i want it to display like this http://www.example.com/Mobiles